# Using jq, convert array of objects to object with named keys

Tags: json, object, key, command-line-interface, jq

Given a json file in the format as :

```
[
 {
  name : "A",
  value : "1"
 },
 {
  name : "B",
  value : "5"
 },
 {
  name : "E",
  value : "8"
 }
]
```

How would I convert it to something like this using jq:

```
{
 "A" : {
   name : "A",
   value : "1"
 },
 "B" : {
  name : "B",
  value : "5"
 },
 "E" : {
  name : "E",
  value : "8"
 }
}
```

`jq '{(.[].name) : "the name"}' 'myfile.json'` gets me an object with [].name keys but how do I assign the object to it?

Comment: Can you post some code. This site is not intended for give full  resolutions for your exercises

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
map( { (.name|tostring): . } ) | add
```

(The `tostring` is for safety/robustness.)

#### INDEX/1

If your jq has `INDEX/1` (introduced after the release of version 1.5), you can simply write:

```
INDEX(.name)
```

Comment: It would need an `add` at the end though, since he want the result as an object.

Comment: Thanks, @JeffMercado.

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely. Still trying to get used to the power of jq but often the examples I find are too simple or too complicated.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm dumb, but can you give a full example of how to use `INDEX`? I'm getting: jq: error: INDEX/1 is not defined at <top-level> -- but I do have jq 1.5

Comment: "after" means "after".  For its definition, google for: def INDEX builtin.jq

Comment: This will include `.name` in the value-objects, which might be redundant. You can remove it with `{ (.name|tostring): del(.name) }`

Answer (score 41):

Just build up a new object going through the items in the array.  Add the items to the object with the `name` as the key.

```
reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.name] = $i)
```

Comment: reduce is much more efficient than INDEX.

Comment: ... and more flexible since you can do transformations on-the-fly, and more familiar to JS devs