# Use jq to convert an array to an object by non-unique keys

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bo",
    "type": "dog"
  },
  {
    "name": "Roxer",
    "type": "dog"
  },
  {
    "name": "Paws",
    "type": "cat"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to convert it to an object keyed by `type`, like this:

```
{
  "dog": [
    {
      "name": "Bo",
      "type": "dog"
    },
    {
      "name": "Roxer",
      "type": "dog"
    }
  ],
  "cat": [
    {
      "name": "Paws",
      "type": "cat"
    }
  ]
}
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428521/1377021) which uses map, but it assumes the `type` is unique and doesn't convert it to an array:

```
reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.type] = $i)
```

The first time a value is inserted, it should be inserted as `[$i]`. Any other time, it should append `[] + $i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case differs from [the one you found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428521/7839189) because you are putting objects into an array. Try this modification of Jeff Mercado's solution.

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.type] += [$i])'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way using `group_by()` on the `.type` field and then create the final result with `.type` as the key

```
jq 'group_by(.type)[] | { (.[0].type) : . }'
```

The only difference in this approach, is `group_by()` does a sort by the `.type` field before producing the result, so the order of keys will be different.