# Reshape a array to object with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am learning advance concepts of jq. And I made a tiny json with array with some films of Charles Chaplin...well this array in json:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "The Great Dictator",
        "year": 1940,
        "country": "USA",
        "genre": "political satire"
    },
    {
        "title": "Modern Times ",
        "year": 1936,
        "country": "USA",
        "genre": "comedy"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Gold Rush",
        "year": 1925,
        "country": "USA",
        "genre": "comedy"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Kid",
        "year": 1921,
        "country": "USA",
        "genre": "drama"
    }
]
```

And I want to convert or reshape into a object with the genres as the keys and the list of the films as array (comedy is only has two element in the array):

```json
{
    "comedy": [
        {
            "title": "Modern Times ",
            "year": 1936,
            "country": "USA"
        },
        {
            "title": "The Gold Rush",
            "year": 1925,
            "country": "USA"
        }
    ],
    "political satire":  [
        {
            "title": "The Great Dictator",
            "year": 1940,
            "country": "USA"
        }
    ],
    "drama": [
        {
            "title": "The Kid",
            "year": 1921,
            "country": "USA"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I can't do it. I trying the first step to create a object with genre and foo string as var, but it fails: `cat c.json | jq '{.[] | (.genre): "foo" ]}'`

Comment: I find this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427725/using-jq-convert-array-of-objects-to-object-with-named-keys but `cat c.json | jq 'INDEX(.genre)'` comedy entry has only element.

Comment: And with `cat c.json | jq '[.[] | {(.genre): [.]}] | add'` does same of previous comment...comedy has only one film.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in three lines:

```
[group_by(.genre)[]
 | {(.[0].genre): map_values(del(.genre))}] 
| add
```

### `aggregate_by/3`

The relevant generic abstraction here is:

```
def aggregate_by(s; f; g):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|f] += [$x|g]);
```

This allows the solution to be written directly as:

```
aggregate_by(.[]; .genre; del(.genre))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found:

```
$ cat c.json | jq '
  group_by(.genre)
  | map({"genre": .[0].genre, 
         "film": map(. | del(.genre))})
  | [ .[] | {(.genre): .film}]
  | add'
{
  "comedy": [
    {
      "title": "Modern Times ",
      "year": 1936,
      "country": "USA"
    },
    {
      "title": "The Gold Rush",
      "year": 1925,
      "country": "USA"
    }
  ],
  "drama": [
    {
      "title": "The Kid",
      "year": 1921,
      "country": "USA"
    }
  ],
  "political satire": [
    {
      "title": "The Great Dictator",
      "year": 1940,
      "country": "USA"
    }
  ]
}
```

Maybe it is not the best, because I think there are a lot of steps...but it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified version of Jeff Mercado's answer on the page [you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428521).

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.genre] += [$i])'
```

That groups the objects as you want but leaves the genre key-value pair. You can delete them like so.

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.genre] += [$i|del(.genre)])'
```

Really, this is just a concrete version of peak's "generic abstraction".